# How to log runtime errors on a file with wildfly

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, jboss-logging

I have several web app modules with same groupId deployed on **wildfly 18**, let's say *org.foo.ecommerce*

These modules are configured with its own subgroup , therefore:

1. **module1** - *org.foo.ecommerce.mod1*
2. **module2** - *org.foo.ecommerce.mod2*
3. **module3** - *org.foo.ecommerce.mod3*

So I configured wildfly with an handler for each module, like the following:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MOD1_HANDLER">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="log.path" path="mod1.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>

<logger category="org.foo.ecommerce.mod1" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <handlers>
        <handler name="MOD1_HANDLER"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Now, if for some reason a NullPointerException is thrown, I can find it ONLY on wildfly server.log.

How can I display all exceptions on the module that belongs from ?

**UPDATE**

This is the stacktrace on console / server.log

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:456)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-
```

Notice that even if I declare my own exception the behaviour is the same

```
@javax.ejb.ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Comment: Can you post the log entry that contains the NPE?

Comment: I have updated the question, see on bottom section

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `NullPointerException` is always logged to the `server.log` is because it's coming from RESTEasy. Any server level modules will log at the servers log configuration level. If a deployment creates it's own log configuration only log messages logged from the deployment are logged to that configuration.

That said there is an open issue, [WFCORE-4807](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-4807), which may allow logs created in server modules to be logged to a deployments configuration.

Comment: Actually is still unresolved, so there s no solution  so far?

Comment: Well for the moment the trick was to build an Interceptor called from rest API, catch the runtimeexception and log it.

Comment: Correct there is currently no solution other than what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are better to use per deployment logging. That way you get logs for anything based on that deployment, not just based on the package name of the class

Comment: Can I still use jboss logging or I should disable it ? Is there any guide on how to configure per deployment logging?

Comment: UPDATE: I added slf4j-log4j12 library and log4j.properties,  but I can't spot differences on how errors are handled, as I can see NullPointerException logged ONLY on server dev output